# How to ask javascript to wait an end of executing external application?

Tags: javascript, wait, external-process

Colls, hello.
My javascript run an external .bat file:

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        objShell.ShellExecute("start.bat", "Main.bat c:\pr  ext.dat ", "C:\\PR\\", "open", "1");
```

Start.bat file works five minutes. And after that my script continue execute other commands.
My question is «how to ask (let him know) javascript to wait an end of executing Start.bat file?»

The naxt code is not very suitable in my case:

```
var date = new Date();
var curDate = null;

do { curDate = new Date(); } 
while(curDate-date < millis);
```

Comment: Are you running this from wsf-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure about the time your Main.bat needs to execute, you can use this:

```
WScript.Sleep(50000);
```

WSH Language reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Sleep method: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t81adfd(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t81adfd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it works!!! But unfortunatly I am not sure about how long main.bat will work (today main.bat works 1 min, and tomorow it may work five minutes) =(. Could you recommend me anything and thank you for helping once again.

Comment: @May12 If you have a clue of the maximum time main.bat will take, you can use that time as a delay (+ some extra to be sure). I think you could also detect a return value from main.bat. Behind this link you'll find everything you'll need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Teemu as I read really i should use WshShell.Run method:       var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
  intReturn = WshShell.Run("C:\\PR\\_start.bat " & "Main.bat c:\pr ext.dat", 1, TRUE); but it still does not work =(( p.s. last parameter (TRUE) is resposible for waiting external app end

Comment: Hmm... I don't know what to say, `WScript.Run()` has been working in my applications. However, I think `TRUE` is undefined, use `true` instead. And you can try to use the method straight in wsf, without definiting a new ActiveXObject, just `WScript.Run(your_parameters);`